# MYSQL: How to fill null values in column with the previous entry?

Tags: mysql

I've got a program at work that exports to CSV but leaves blanks in the most irritable places. I want to view the carrier and destination on the same row and currently the carrier is 1 row above the destination like below:

I have a database that is like the following:
     `|Key|Carrier ||Destination|`
     `|-------------------------|`
     `| 1 | HULL2  ||           |`
     `| 2 |        ||  C14A102  |`
     `| 3 | DONC1  ||           |`
     `| 4 |        ||  D15A012  |`

What I want:

```
 |Key|Carrier ||Destination|
 |-------------------------|
 | 1 | HULL2  ||           |
 | 2 | HULL2  ||  C14A102  |
 | 3 | DONC1  ||           |
 | 4 | DONC1  ||  D15A012  |
```

Either that or insert a new column with the information from carrier column.

Sorry if this is confusing its confusing me to explain it!

James

Comment: `its confusing me to explain it!` ... You took the words out of my mouth.  Can you show us expected output?

Comment: Sorry Tim I'm trying to fix now!!

Comment: You need to have some field to `order by` to get the next row.

Comment: Fixed the post sorry new to posting :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, by cloning another table and then deleting it:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(Key_id INT PRIMARY KEY, Carrier CHAR(20), Destination CHAR(20));
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1, 'HULL2', ''),(2,'','C14A102'),(3,'DONC1',''),(4,'','D15A012');

CREATE TABLE t2 LIKE t1;
INSERT INTO t2 SELECT * FROM t1;

SELECT * FROM t1;
UPDATE t1 SET Carrier = 
    (
    SELECT t2.Carrier
    FROM t2
    WHERE t2.Key_id < t1.Key_id AND t2.Carrier != ''
    ORDER BY t2.Key_id DESC
    LIMIT 1
    )
WHERE Carrier = '';
SELECT * FROM t1;

DROP TABLE t2;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t1;
+--------+---------+-------------+
| Key_id | Carrier | Destination |
+--------+---------+-------------+
|      1 | HULL2   |             |
|      2 |         | C14A102     |
|      3 | DONC1   |             |
|      4 |         | D15A012     |
+--------+---------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE t1 SET Carrier =
    -> (
    -> SELECT t2.Carrier
    -> FROM t2
    -> WHERE t2.Key_id < t1.Key_id AND t2.Carrier != ''
    -> ORDER BY t2.Key_id DESC
    -> LIMIT 1
    -> )
    -> WHERE Carrier = '';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM t1;
+--------+---------+-------------+
| Key_id | Carrier | Destination |
+--------+---------+-------------+
|      1 | HULL2   |             |
|      2 | HULL2   | C14A102     |
|      3 | DONC1   |             |
|      4 | DONC1   | D15A012     |
+--------+---------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Will this work if my table has 1000+ lines with different carrier names?

Comment: Why not? Just replace 't1' with your own table name. You can give a try. @James

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the column 'key' can be trusted in this way, I would update with a self join where the join uses `key = key+1`, and then make sure it's only affecting even rows.

```
UPDATE tablename as even_row JOIN tablename as odd_row 
ON even_row.Key = odd_row.Key + 1 
SET even_row.Carrier = odd_row.Carrier 
WHERE odd_row.Key % 2;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am getting "#1054 - Unknown column 'cur_row.id' in 'where clause'".

Comment: I've edited my answer to use your column names, but I'll have to lean on you to see what I'm trying to suggest and adapt as appropriate to your case.